# openlayers - how can i rotate the image layer

Tags: javascript, openlayers

i have an OpenLayers.Layer.Image object.. is there any way to rotate it using openlayers ?

please don't suggest to rotate the entire div using jquery, 
when i do this i'm losing the zooming and panning effect of the openlayers..

Comment: Do you need to rotate it dynamically? If not you could just rotate the image before you create the OpenLayers.Layer.Image object from it.

Comment: yes, i need to be able to adjust it's angle on code..

Answer (score 4):

There's not really a way to do this with an OpenLayers image.  You can, however, workaround this by using a vector layer.

**Using Vectors to Rotate an Image**

If you'd like to add a rotated image to the map, as well as maintain zoom and pan features of the map relative to the image, you can do the following:

Create a vector layer, and set the `externalGraphic` = your image src:

```
var styleMap = new OpenLayers.Style({
    externalGraphic: "${getUrl}" // attribute replacement syntax
}, {context: context});
var vectorLayer = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("My Image Overlay", {
    styleMap: styleMap
});
map.addLayers([vectorLayer]);
```

Next, create a vector feature whose external graphic matches the source of your image:

```
var newPoint = new OpenLayers.Geometry.Point(x, y);
var pointFeature = new OpenLayers.Feature.Vector(newPoint);
pointFeature.attributes.externalGraphic = "path/to/image/src/";
```

Add the feature to your vector layer:

```
vectorLayer.addFeatures([pointFeature]);
```

Then rotate it.  For this you simply need to configure a point of origin about which your image will rotate:

```
var origin = new OpenLayers.Geometry.Point(x, y); // should match coordinates of pointFeature
var center = new OpenLayers.Feature.Vector(origin);
vectorLayer.addFeatures([center]);
```

You can optionally change style attributes of your origin of rotation to hide it from the map if desired.

Finally, change the orientation of your pointFeature to place as desired:

```
pointFeature.geometry.rotate(angle, origin);
pointFeature.layer.drawFeature(pointFeature);
```

More examples of how to do this [here](http://openlayers.org/dev/examples/rotate-features.html) and [here](http://openlayers.org/dev/examples/styles-rotation.html).

Comment: thanks, sorry for the long response time, i tried it, but now i have another problem.. when i drag the map to the side, when half of it is out of the screen it disappears from the screen..